# problem with creating column name dynamically in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe dynamically. So far I'm fine with capturing data within the dataframe, but not with the name of the columns.

I also want the name of the columns to be based on the 'category' of the data that comes with the record that I am reading in my function, but I always get the last one.

```
def funct_example(client):
documents = [ v_document ]

poller = client.begin_analyze_entities(documents)
result = poller.result()

docs = [doc for doc in result if not doc.is_error]
i = 1    
df_final = pd.DataFrame()       
    
for idx, doc in enumerate(docs):      
    for relation in doc.entity_relations:
        for role in relation.roles:
            name = str([format(entity.category)]) + str(i)  # <---- THIS LINE ALWAYS IS THE LAST REGISTER

            d = {name : "'{}' with entity '{}'".format(role.name, role.entity.text)} # <---THIS IS OK                 
            df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[0])                
            df_final = pd.concat([df_final, df], axis=1)
            i = i + 1
            display(df_final)
return(df_final)
df_new_2 = funct_example(client)
```

I've tried adding an extra loop between creating the dataframe sentence and concat function like so:

```
for col in df.columns:
    name = str([format(entity.category)]) + str(i)  
    df = df.rename(columns={col: name })
```

But the last category still appears in the column name...

How can I solve that?

From already thank you very much.

SOLUTION:

```
    for idx, doc in enumerate(docs):      
    for relation in doc.entity_relations:
        for role in relation.roles:
            name = 'Relation_' + format(relation.relation_type) + '_' + str(i)  
            d = {name : "'{}' with entity '{}'".format(role.name, role.entity.text)} 
            df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[0])
            df_final = pd.concat([df_final, df], axis=1)
            i = i + 1
            display(df_final)
return(df_final)
df_relations = funct_example(client)
```

Regards!! :D

Comment: Please provide an example of the desired output.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: Thanks furas for you time. I gave me an idea with your comment. I postead a update in the code with solution. Thanks you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its difficult to suggest a solution without knowing the properties of all the objects being used.

'entity' object, is not defined within the function, so is it a global variable?

Does the role has 'entity', which then has the 'category' property? Im assuming as such, since role does have entity property

```
d = {name : "'{}' with entity '{}'".format(role.name, role.entity.text)} # <---THIS IS OK
```

Beside, the name variable while initialized is not used.

maybe you try

```
name = str([format(role.entity.category)]) + str(i)
```

Comment: Thanks you for you time Naveed. You gave me an idea with your comment, I have divided the analysis according to the desired output and I have managed to find the solution. I just put a RETURN() outside the loop along with the display(df). I have updated the code with the solution. Thank you!!